# How to create Policies without parameters in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a project to add edit contacts.

To restrict the user can add/edit their own contacts, So added policy ContactPolicy as below

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use App\User;
use App\Contact;

class ContactPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function before($user, $ability)
    {
        if ($user->isAdmin == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function add_contact(User $user)
    {
        return $user->id;
    }

    public function update_contact(User $user, Contact $contact)
    {
        return $user->id === $contact->user_id;
    }
}
```

And registered in AuthServiceProvider as below

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Contact::class => ContactPolicy::class,
    ];
```

To restrict adding of contact by current user I added Gate in my controller function as below without passing parameters

```
if (Gate::denies('add_contact')) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
```

Even if current user tries to add contact, it shows Unauthorized message.

How will I solve this problem?

Comment: The method has to return a boolean, but your *add_contact()* method returns `return $user->id;` and it's probably not working because you require a parameter **$user** which you don't include when you call the gate from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Policies are intended to have all authorization logic related to a certain class of resource in one place.

So, you define `Contact::class => ContactPolicy::class` meaning the ContactPolicy has all policies regarding Contacts. When you write `Gate::denies('add_contact')`, how could the framework know which policy to search? You have to pass an object of type Contact as second parameter in order to access the ContactPolicy.

Anyway, there is in fact a place to write authorization logic which is not particular to any class of resource. In the method `boot` of `AuthServiceProvider` you could add

```
 $gate->define('add_contact', function ($user) {
        return $user->id;
 });
```

By the way, what's the intention with returning the user id? I think you just need to return a boolean.

Also, if you are checking the permission within a controller, you should just call `$this->authorize('add_contact')` and the controller itself will check and return a Forbidden response (for which the proper code is 403, not 401) if it fails, no need to return it yourself.